ASP.NET Core MVC : static file response with prefix when using nginx ingress rewrite
I'm not a .NET developer but gotta provide a sample ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller) to a client. But I have a problem when deploying it onto Kubernetes.
For example, when I click Privacy button, I get 404 errors.

//ex.
// root
www.example.com/custom/path

// Desired
www.example.com/custom/path/Home/Privacy

// Actual - 404 error as ingress cannot route it.
www.example.com/Home/Privacy

Code
I'm using nginx-ingress for routing traffics.
The ingress looks like (using rewrite)
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    //...
    // I have to use rewrite
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    //...

spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: www.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: dotnet-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
            path: /custom/path/?(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific


Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    @* Add below line for setting prefix for href in link tag *@
    <base href="/custom/path/">
    @* ... *@
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MVPPractice.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">MVPPractice</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    @* ... *@

    <script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>

Traffic flow
ASP.NET program's base is root(/) not /custom/path, that's why I use nginx-ingress's rewrite.

Current Issue

Request www.example.com/custom/path/


Response 200
href of <a> is /Home/Privacy which leads to www.example.com/Home/Privacy, it is supposed to be /custom/path/Home/Privacy so that it leads to www.example.com/custom/path/Home/Privacy.


Click the link <a>


Requests www.example.com/Home/Privacy
Response 404 (because nginx-ingress cannot route it)

How do I set prefix for static file responses?

Can you show us your program.cs file? You should have a line something like app.UseStaticFiles(); in there - do you?

@marc_s thx I'ved added Program.cs and _Layout.cshtml. I've got that line as I barely changed the code.

I suspect something is off with the url rewrite in the ingress. Can you see in the aspnet core logs what url is being requested from the app?

Make sure you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-9.0#forwarded-headers So long as your proxy sets X-Forwarded-Prefix and you configure the server to trust it, then everything should work without hard-coding anything.

@ESG No logs as nginx-ingress failed the route the request, it couldn't even reach asp.net program. The requested url need be based on root from dotnet's perspective.

You could try this below code to rewrite the url to your custom path to avoid the 404 error:
Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the application to use a base path
app.UsePathBase("/custom/path"); 

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.Run();

YAML:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dotnet-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /custom/path/$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: www.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /custom/path/?(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: dotnet-service
                port:
                  number: 8080

If you only would like to serve the static file you could use the RequestPath something like below:
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    RequestPath = "/StaticFiles"
});

If you would like entire application, including routes, controllers, and static files use the path like /custom/path use app.UsePathBase("/custom/path");

The rewrite-target can't be changed as it is intended. Inside the container(ASP.NET), the base is root but outside the kubernetes, it's /custom/path (from user's perspective)
